# how to make responsive table scroll hidden when screen size normal in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make my bootstrap table not to display right left scroll when screen size is normal when table is set to responsive. Do I miss any step here ? How can I fix this ?

```
<div class="table-responsive">              
    <table id="inlist" class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>x</th>
                <th>y</th>
                <th>z</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the image for normal screen

[image]

Comment: By default it works the way you described. Look for margins on your table to see if those are making it go beyond 100%.

Comment: you could hide the overflow, but there is probably another issue at hand such as width + padding or width + margin that is causing the overflow.  Could look into box-sizing: border-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a word pad, make a new document, and type

```
#inlist{overflow:hidden; word-wrap:normal | break-word; }
```

Save it as a (insert name).css and add it to your html. It's easier this way than piecing in a  in the html. With css, you can control the style of everything in the webpage and keep the html clutter free.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done css so I may be wrong in the syntax.

Comment: so i remove  <div class="table-responsive">  ?

Comment: If you want to put in he html, just under the main table body, add <style scoped > what I posted above followed by </style>

Comment: Ultimately I suggest adding a css file.

Answer (score 2):

Just add up-to the div table-responsive

```
<style>
    .table-responsive {
        overflow-x: visible; 
    }
</style>
```