# How to give a responsive table in mobile layout using java script, html, css without bottom scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a table with 16 columns.I need this table structure adaptable in all devices.

[image]

For eg:
In desktop - I need to display all 16 columns.
In Tablet - I need to display only 4 columns.Rest of the columns should be available with the TD (hidden).On clicking respective column, I need to show the hidden TD opening below the row.

[image]

[image]

I no need for bottom scroll.

On clicking name 2, the hidden column 2a, 2b, 2c, 2d will be visible.
Similarly, On clicking Email 2, the hidden column 2e, 2f, 2g, 2h will be visible.

How to solve this using table?

```js
function show(elem){
    var sub_div="col_";
    for(i=1;i<=8;i++){
        if(sub_div+i!=elem){
            if(document.getElementById(sub_div+i))
                document.getElementById(sub_div+i).style.display="none";
        }
        else{
            if(document.getElementById(elem))
                document.getElementById(elem).style.display="block";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

 table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     width: 100%;
 }
 table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td p{
 display: none;
}



}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     width: 800px;
 }
 table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.full{
 /*position: relative;*/
}

.main{
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
 position: relative;
 left:0;
 top:0;
}
.secondary{
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 width: 800px;
 margin:auto;
 display: none;
 /*top:30px;*/
}
.secondary td{
 width: 200px;
}

}
```

```html
<table class="main1">
 <tr class="main">
  <td class="full"><p onclick="show('col_1')">Name 1</p>
   <table class="secondary" id="col_1">
    <tr>
     <td>1a</td>
     <td>1b</td>
     <td>1c</td>
     <td>1d</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  
  <td><p onclick="show('col_2')">Email 1</p>
   <table  class="secondary" id="col_2">
    <tr>
     <td>1e</td>
     <td>1f</td>
     <td>1g</td>
     <td>1h</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td><p onclick="show('col_3')">Validity 1</p>
   <table  class="secondary" id="col_3">
    <tr>
     <td>1i</td>
     <td>1j</td>
     <td>1k</td>
     <td>1l</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>

  <td><p onclick="show('col_4')">Location 1</p>
   <table  class="secondary" id="col_4">
    <tr>
     <td>1m</td>
     <td>1n</td>
     <td>1O</td>
     <td>1p</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>


 <tr class="main">
  <td><p onclick="show('col_5')">Name 2</p>
   <table class="secondary" id="col_5">
    <tr>
     <td>2a</td>
     <td>2b</td>
     <td>2c</td>
     <td>2d</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  
  <td><p onclick="show('col_6')">Email 2</p>
   <table  class="secondary" id="col_6">
    <tr>
     <td>2e</td>
     <td>2f</td>
     <td>2g</td>
     <td>2h</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td><p onclick="show('col_7')">Validity 2</p>
   <table  class="secondary" id="col_7">
    <tr>
     <td>2i</td>
     <td>2j</td>
     <td>2k</td>
     <td>2l</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>

  <td><p onclick="show('col_8')">Location 2</p>
   <table  class="secondary" id="col_8">
    <tr>
     <td>2m</td>
     <td>2n</td>
     <td>2O</td>
     <td>2p</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

I tried to do the code.But I am facing some problem.

On clicking Name 1 the invisible row has to come between row 1 and row 2. The row 2 should automatically come down.

But In my code the hidden row overlaps.
How to solve this.Please help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733562/how-to-make-responsive-table-scroll-hidden-when-screen-size-normal-in-bootstrap) might help................!!

Comment: Use Bootstrap   it is easy

Comment: Give a class to the TD's that you are going to hide and use @media rule to hide them as the screnn size reduces.

Comment: Refer, if helps :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792728/use-jquery-to-move-columns-in-order-to-next-tr-when-page-is-resized